# Changing Value of a Keyboard key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I seem to have broken my right arrow key on my mac which is making programming VERY tedious. I can't afford to fix it right now. Is there any way I can change the values of keyboard keys? Or perhaps an easy shortcut to move right spaces through code?

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/

Just rebind a key you are not using (or make a hotkey) to right arrow.